# Xdocument and linq - doesn't cycle thru the elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Given the xml from the request (with XXX replaced by whatever user wanted), cant really figure out why it's not returning 2 test objects to the list as it should.

```
String YouTubeXML = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/XXXXXXXXX/uploads?orderby=published");
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(YouTubeXML);

List<dynamic> videos = (from i in xDoc.Descendants("entry")
                        select new
                        {
                            //Just declaring something random
                            Title = i.Element("id").Value

                        }).ToList<dynamic>();
```

And the XML structure looks something like this:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
<id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/XXXXXXXX/uploads</id>
<author>
  <name>XXXXXXXX</name>
  <uri>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/XXXXXXXX</uri>
</author>
<generator version="2.1" uri="http://gdata.youtube.com">YouTube data API</generator>
<openSearch:totalResults>5</openSearch:totalResults>
<openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
<openSearch:itemsPerPage>25</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
<entry>
  <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/video1</id>
  <published>date</published>
  <updated>date</updated>
  <author>
    <name>name</name>
    <uri>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/XXXXXXX</uri>
  </author>
  <yt:hd />
  <media:group>
    <yt:duration seconds="179" />
  </media:group>
  <gd:rating average="4.703704" max="5" min="1" numRaters="81" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#overall" />
  <yt:statistics favoriteCount="0" viewCount="6004" />
</entry>
<entry>
  <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/video2</id>
  <published>date</published>
  <updated>date</updated>
  <author>
    <name>name</name>
<uri>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/XXXXXXX</uri>
  </author>
  <yt:hd />
  <media:group>
    <yt:duration seconds="179" />
  </media:group>
  <gd:rating average="4.703704" max="5" min="1" numRaters="81"         rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#overall" />
  <yt:statistics favoriteCount="0" viewCount="6004" />
</entry>
</feed>
```

What could possible be going wrong? The XML is being received and parsed, so it's the query that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the fact, that XML uses namespaces, so your query has to use namespaces too:

```
var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
var videos = (from i in xDoc.Root.Elements(ns + "entry")
              select new
              {
                  Title = (string)i.Element(ns + "id")
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew i was missing something really basic that I was unaware of. Thumbs up!